# should I cofigure clustered MS DTC on windows 2012 r2 used for MS SQL server 2014 that runs as failover claster from mentioned 2 machines

Tags: msdtc, failovercluster

Usualy i use ms sql server without high avalability. Usualy I need configure os local ms DTC to my transactionScope transaction works. This transaction are open in c#code in application server and then ms sql server modify DB within transactions. So, in this case local ms dtc configuration is required: allow inbound, outboud traffic, mutual authentification. 
But is it sufficient to confige local ms DTC on both claster DB machines only or should i configure **clastered DTC**? Db cluster based on Windows 2012 r2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - I configured local DTC on each of two machines (not clustered DTC) and failover cluster is working well for a couple of months.